# Package is declared in module, which is not in the module graph

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

Сегодня запустил свой проект, обновил Intellij IDEA и произошло нечто такое, из-за чего я не могу писать свой прекрасный код. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая вот ерунда была не только с этим пакетом, но и со всеми другими пакетами, которые имею отношение к JavaFX, но с ними я проделал это и проблема вроде как ушла[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу же я с каждым пакетом такую ерунду вытворять, тем более что эти пакеты надо было бы писать вручную по памяти, Intellij IDEA не могла мне предложить классы JavaFX'a в окошке с классами, названия которых походят на то, что я написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте явно указать опцию [`--add-modules`](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/modules/root-modules.html) для компиляции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и в конфигурации запуска, чтобы определить [список корневых модулей](https://blog.codefx.org/java/five-command-line-options-to-hack-the-java-9-module-system/#Extending-The-Module-Graph-With--add-modules). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Вы добавите опцию  [`java.se.ee`](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules), то получите доступ ко всем модулям Java EE.

---

Кроме того, данная ошибка уже активно обсуждалась на сайте компании [JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000162524-Package-javax-xml-bind-annotations-is-declared-in-module-java-xml-bind-which-is-not-in-the-module-graph).
Также подробнее можете познакомиться с данной проблемой [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421876/8370915) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359097/8370915).

Comment: Это считай то же самое что я показал на 2-ом изображении... Что же, ладно, пока никакой другой альтернатив нет буду делать так... Вам спасибо за ответ

Comment: @ProstoCoder, применение опции `--add-modules` - да, а вот с `java.se.ee` можно подключить несколько модулей (правда Java EE). К слову, Java 11 удаляет модули Java EE и там уже придется смотреть в [сторону альтернатив](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48204154/8370915).